# Why can't I use char-alpha in spec generator?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm using a spec which looks like this:

```clj
(ns blah
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
            [clojure.spec.gen.alpha :as gen]))
(s/def ::user
  (s/with-gen
    (s/and string? #(re-matches #"^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}$" %))
    #(gen/string-alphanumeric)))
```

It works ok when generating examples, although often hits the 100-try limit. I really want a `gen/string-alpha`, although this generator is not available.

When I try to make it:

```clj
#(gen/fmap clojure.string/join (gen/vector gen/char-alpha 3 20))
```

...it says "First arg to vector must be a generator".

Why isn't `gen/char-alpha` (which [points at](https://github.com/clojure/spec.alpha/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/spec/gen/alpha.clj#L118) `clojure.test.check.generators`) working?

Answer (score 2):

Oopsie needed to read the docs:

```clj
clojure.spec.gen.alpha/char-alpha
([& args])
  Fn returning clojure.test.check.generators/char-alpha
```

The correct form is:

```clj
#(gen/fmap clojure.string/join (gen/vector (gen/char-alpha) 3 20))
```